# How to do multi-pass rendering on customised shaders?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, game-engine, shaders

I'm using customised shader to achieve a specific aspect. I'm confused by the fact it is dealt with by the game engine, not the rendering engine (??), but my actual question is: how do I do multi-pass rendering? I need to access the depth, color and normal buffer from previous passes to do a toon-outline effect. I couldn't find how to invoke the shader directly on the involved Python script.

Comment: Are you using the game engine? Or BI/Cycles? (I noticed that you included a [tag:game-engine] tag, but your second sentence is confusing me)..

Comment: I'm also confused. You should add more info including any tutorials that you are making use of.  Usually for game engines you'd probably want to render each pass to an FBO then load them all into a shader that is attached to a screen aligned quad and do whatever you want with the shader code.  For BI or Cycles you can use the Compositor to render multiple passes then use nodes to do what you want to do.  If you are using GLSL then you might want to check out the following page http://prideout.net/blog/?p=22. It shows how to build up a toon shader in stages and only requires one pass.